# Passenger installation with nginx fails

Tags: ruby, passenger, failed-installation

I'm running an ubuntu 9.10 server on an amd-64 platform.  Everything's pretty much standard, and I've got Sinatra 0.94 running on a ruby 1.8 installation.  I want to install passenger in order to easily configure ssl.

The problem is, it fails to find the installer.

I run

```
sudo gem install passenger
```

or

```
sudo gem install -r passenger
```

and then the next line,

```
passenger-install-nginx-module
```

or

```
passenger-install-apache2-module
```

both fail because the path isn't found.

Is there something I'm forgetting here?  Shouldn't it just work, straight up, once the gem is installed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

apparently, the gem is installed in a place that's off the path, according to

http://groups.google.com/group/phusion-passenger/browse_thread/thread/78ca12c4838034a6/b5a3c7a00a871283?lnk=gst&q=ubuntu+9.10#b5a3c7a00a871283

Frustrating error, which is why I leave this question rather than delete it (and, with the upvote, I think I'm not the only one with the problem).

Answer (score 37):

A bit late for an answer I guess, but actually, the correct way of running the Phusion Passenger installer for nginx, when using RVM, is to use `rvmsudo` as in:

```
rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module
```

Credits go to [this blog post](http://craiccomputing.blogspot.com/2010/10/passenger-3-nginx-and-rvm-on-mac-os-x.html),

Answer (score 25):

I got it working with

```
rvmsudo `which passenger-install-nginx-module`
```

Comment: That one was a god sent.. Thanx.

Comment: Me too. Maybe because I use zsh (with oh-my-zsh).

Answer (score 12):

according to this issue on github: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1307

seems like you have to do full path:

this worked for me:

```
which passenger-install-nginx-module

rvmsudo ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327-new/gems/passenger-3.0.18/bin/passenger-install-nginx-module
```

Comment: or you can also do: `$ rvmsudo $(which passenger-install-nginx-module)`

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. You need to add gems to your system PATH, paste this into your shell:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin
```

or, to make it permanent add it to your bashrc, usually here: ~/.bashrc

You can also execute just passenger-install-nginx-module by going to the directory at: `/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin`

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I know you already answered the question, but figured I'd chime in with a cent or two.

I recently did a similar nginx install, but chose to go with RVM for managing Ruby versions, which requires us to NOT use sudo.

I recommend this route because all versions of Ruby and all your gems are organized neatly in your home directory. Doing so will also require you to compile nginx manually, which certainly helps understand the pipes a little.

You can compile nginx manually using the "--add-module=/home/user/path_to_passenger_gem/ext," but you'll want to read up RVM's instructions very carefully...really, don't skip a line as they are very concise.

Here's a link to RVM's instructions:

http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/passenger/

and to the Nginx manual instructions (which you probably already skimmed).

http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#_installing_phusion_passenger_for_nginx_manually

Comment: Thanks for the tips; as an nginx newb, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I have got a bit of information on my [blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20130404071904/http://three99.com/posts/install-ssl-support-on-nginx) regarding setting up nginx with passenger (and ssl in this case). Perhaps it is of use since it goes through the whole process of recompiling nginx with options.