# Error installing Passenger with nginx on OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: nginx, rvm, passenger, homebrew, failed-installation

So I'm following this [tutorial](http://shapeshed.com/installing-passenger-3-with-rvm-and-nginx-on-osx/), and about half way through compiling nginx, 'It looks like something went wrong'.

So, I have RVM installed and working, and I also have the Passenger gem installed. I also installed nginx using Homebrew, which also works.

So then, I try:

```
rvmsudo `which passenger-install-nginx-module`
```

Which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13540132/962144).

When prompted if I want to install a new version of nginx, or recompile the Homebrew one with Passenger support, I choose option 2. When it asks where the source code is, put in:

```
/Library/Caches/Homebrew/nginx-1.2.6
```

(I tar'd the download, and I've checked that everything is present and correct in that directory.)

Then, when it asks me where to install the new recompiled nginx, I say the same directory as the old one:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.2.6/sbin
```

I leave the extra arguments blank, and hit enter twice.

It runs for a few minutes, starts compiling and installing nginx, but then fails. Here's the last few lines:

```
objs/ngx_modules.o \
    /Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/passenger-3.0.19/ext/nginx/../common/libpassenger_common.a /Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/passenger-3.0.19/ext/nginx/../common/libboost_oxt.a -lstdc++ -lpthread -lm -lpcre -lssl -lcrypto -lz
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_pcre_free_study", referenced from:
      _ngx_pcre_free_studies in ngx_regex.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [objs/nginx] Error 1
make: *** [build] Error 2
--------------------------------------------

It looks like something went wrong

Please read our Users guide for troubleshooting tips:

   /Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/passenger-3.0.19/doc/Users guide Nginx.html

If that doesn't help, please use our support facilities at:

   https://www.phusionpassenger.com

We'll do our best to help you.
```

I've checked that nginx is not running, and I've also tried uninstalling the Homebrew version of nginx, re-running the script with the defaults, and it still fails on me.

I have Mountain Lion installed with the most recent version of XCode and Command Line Utilities. Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ended up being a problem with `pcre`. I simply ran

```
brew update pcre
```

And ran the installer again with the same options as before, and it worked.

Comment: Did this solve the problem?
It should be `brew upgrade pcre`, probably.
I tried upgrading pcre, but Homebrew reports that the pcre-8.32 is the latest one and is installed in my machine.