# rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module : No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, rvm, passenger

I am trying to install passenger/nginx onto ubuntu 12.10.

When I try to run **rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module** I get:

```
/usr/bin/env: passenger-install-nginx-module: No such file or directory
```

$PATH results in

```
bash: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:
/usr/local/games:/home/deploy/.rvm/bin:/home/deploy/.rvm/bin: No such file or directory
```

RVM INFO:

```
ruby-2.0.0-p247:

  system:
    uname:       "Linux rails 3.5.0-17-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 9 19:31:23 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"
    system:      "ubuntu/12.10/x86_64"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.2.37(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)"
    zsh:         " => not installed"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.22.3 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "22 hours 56 minutes 7 seconds ago"
    path:         "/home/deploy/.rvm"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "2.0.0p247"
    date:         "2013-06-27"
    platform:     "x86_64-linux"
    patchlevel:   "2013-06-27 revision 41674"
    full_version: "ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247"
    ruby:         "/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin:/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/home/deploy/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
    GEM_HOME:     "/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247"
    GEM_PATH:     "/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247:/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247"
    IRBRC:        "/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

Also, if i try to run **gem install passenger**

```
bash: /usr/bin/gem: /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I think this is due to me having an incorrect system wide install of RVM. i went and installed a user install of RVM, and thought i had properly removed the system wide RVM install, but it looks like somehow its still pointing to /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 which is no longer in existence.

Comment: What are you trying to do? installing passenger on nginx module with rvm?

Comment: yes. i am trying to run **rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module**

Comment: Why are you trying to install it with ruby VM? Does not it should be run against system's installer/package manager

Comment: When i try to run passenger-install-nginx-module from my "deploy" user it tells me it does not have permissions to write to /opt/nginx. when i switch to user root, and then try to run it, it tells me passenger-install-nginx-module: command not found

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking a this thread:

[Passenger installation with nginx fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225881/passenger-installation-with-nginx-fails)

I had to run the full path to the installer

```
rvmsudo ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.14/bin/passenger-install-nginx-module
```

Answer (score 2):

just run `passenger-install-nginx-module` it is not required to `sudo` it, the command will instruct you what to do in case it can not do it.

Comment: When i try to run passenger-install-nginx-module from my "deploy" user it tells me it does not have permissions to write to /opt/nginx and to run from the root user... when i switch to root, and then try to run it, it tells me passenger-install-nginx-module: command not found

Answer (score 0):

```
 cd cd_to_your_current_folder
 gem install passenger --no-rdoc --no-ri
```

then do

```
 rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module
```